# How to upload .gpx.xml files into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, xml, gpx

I have a file with the following extension `.gpx.xml` taken from the following website: [walking](https://www.walkingbritain.co.uk/walk-3446-description)

However, I don't know how to import the file when it's both in `.xml` format and `.gpx` format. What methods are available to me, as I would like to read this into QGIS. It's gps data however I'm not sure of it's structure, so it could be point data. Therefore I would like to find this out.

Comment: GPX is an XML file format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oen your QGIS project and from the main toolbar select Layer -> Add Vector Layer and select the GPX file from the list presented below.

[image]